# Problem with lualatex-dev and TeXGyre Pagella Math

Tags: luatex

The next code with `lualatex-dev` gives warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TeXGyrePagellaMath(1)/m/up' undefined
```

but not with `lualatex`

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex-dev
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\mathrm d z
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unicode-math needs an update to the nfss changes in the latex format. See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/536

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks Ulrike ! I lost 3 hours this morning to know if I had made a mistake. Do you have any advice on how to better search for this kind of information about lualatex-dev ?

Comment: Well my general strategie is to search at most 15 minutes and then to consider where is the right place to ask.